# Padrino Sass in Haml not working

Tags: ruby, sass, sinatra, haml, padrino

I am new to Padrino with little idea of haml/sass following [sample blog tutorial](http://www.padrinorb.com/guides/blog-tutorial) from [padrinorb.com](http://www.padrinorb.com/). I have included sass gem in my sample project.

When I run my sample project changes done to application.sass present in app/stylesheets does not reflect in my haml until I include/link the generated application.css present in public/stylesheets. i.e. My styling works only if I include the below line in my haml

```
 %link(rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/application.css")
```

My doubt is on how this auto linking happening for the sample blog padrinorb.com project but not for my sample project which requires manual linking?

Comment: Have you followed the instructions [here](http://www.padrinorb.com/guides/blog-tutorial#site-layout)?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Iain, My Bad I missed the below line in my code which lead to the css not being included. For anyone who is also stuck, line below is just a padrino way of linking the stylesheet with your haml. Write this in your haml head part as you do for a css.

```
= stylesheet_link_tag 'reset', 'application'
```